# Se puede cambiar el color de un checkbox y un radio button con estilos de Materialiaze?

Tags: html, checkbox, materialize, radiobutton

Quiero cambiar el color de un radio button y un checkbox que tienen estilos de Materialize css. Quiero cambiar el color verde a otro color. Agrego el código:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <label>
         <input type="checkbox" />
         <span>Red</span>
    </label>
     <label>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" checked />
        <span>Red</span>
    </label>
    
         <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

         <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Este es el resultado:
[image: checkbox verde]
[image: radio button verde]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello debes tener en cuenta:

1. Los estilos de `materialize` deben ir en la parte superior entre las etiquetas `<head></head>`
2. Debes crear una hoja de estilos personalizada en tu proyecto
3. Usar la declaración `!important` al final de cada propiedad para dar mayor especificidad a los estilos modificados

Los estilos para cada caso están comentados.

```css
/*Para el checkbox*/
[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:not(.lever):before {
    border-right: 2px solid #a30000 !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a30000 !important;
}

/*Para el radio button*/
[type="radio"]:checked+span:after, 
[type="radio"].with-gap:checked+span:before, 
[type="radio"].with-gap:checked+span:after {
    border: 2px solid #a30000 !important;
    background-color: #a30000 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
    <span>Red</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="group1" type="radio" checked />
    <span>Red</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="group2" type="radio" />
    <span>Red2</span>
  </label>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```