# como cambio el color del check de mat-list-option AngularMaterial

Tags: html, css, angular, material

Por mas que pruebo con diversas formas en `CSS` el color que viene por defecto no cambia de amarillo.

```css
.mat-list-option mat-pseudo-checkbox-inner {
  background-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<mat-list-option>
  <div class=" ">
    <div class=" "></div>
    <div class=" "></div>
    <div class=" "></div>
  </div>
</mat-list-option>
```

**Como se ve:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega un poco mas de contexto para tratar de reproducir el problema en un snippet. Por lo pronto, mira la [respuesta a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536846/se-puede-cambiar-el-color-de-un-checkbox-y-un-radio-button-con-estilos-de-materi/536852#536852), tal vez te pueda ayudar un poco mientras editas tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para poder cambiar el color se utiliza es una propiedad de Angular Material el unico detalle que la gama de colores es nula, cuando encuentre la forma de cambiarlo en base a un css lo publicare:

```
color="warn" Naranja 

color="primary" Morado

<mat-list-option  color="warn" >
<div class=" ">
<div class=" "></div>
<div class=" "></div>
<div class=" "></div>
</div>
</mat-list-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no es la mejor practica utilizar `!important` pero te puede sacar del problema inmediato.

Coloca esta clase en tu css y modifica el color.

```
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-list-option .mdc-checkbox .mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled:checked~.mdc-checkbox__background, .mat-mdc-list-option .mdc-checkbox .mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled:indeterminate~.mdc-checkbox__background, .mat-mdc-list-option .mdc-checkbox .mdc-checkbox__native-control[data-indeterminate=true]:enabled~.mdc-checkbox__background {

border-color: blue !important;
background-color: blue !important;}
```

[image: Asi queda despues del cambio]